# Qual é o post que teve mais voto a favor e contra?

Tags: debate

Gente eu vi post com 40 votos a favor e queria sabe se existe alguém que teve mais e pior em voto.

Se alguém sabe me avise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta mandar listar as perguntas por votos, assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes. Indo nas últimas páginas verá as com mais negativos.

Se quiser saber das respostas (em geral elas estão nas perguntas mais votadas), precisa recorrer ao SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer). Exemplo: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/36656/most-upvoted-answers.

Tem outras lá que mostra as mais negativadas, mais controversas, tem muita *query* pronta e pode criar as suas do zero ou baseadas em alguma existente.

Comment: Essa query do SEDE não da pra fazer assim? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

Comment: Dá sim, nem lembrava disso :)

Comment: @Costamilam A diferença é que no SEDE também [dá para buscar as respostas deletadas](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1075705/most-downvoted-answers) (no caso, para as deletadas só retorna o ID, mas quem tem mais de 10 mil pontos consegue ver acessando `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/ID`)